# Complex JSON to flat JSON Format using JOLT required

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming a very complex array JSON input to a flat JSON format. The Input, Jolt Transformation & output detail is given below.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "guid": 16161616,
  "WebHookId": 1234567890,
  "siteLocation": "offshore",
  "ReferenceCountry": [
    {
      "RefCountry": "DE",
      "Country": "DE"
    },
    {
      "RefCountry": "DE",
      "Country": "BE"
    },
    {
      "RefCountry": "DE",
      "Country": "NL"
    }
  ],
  "WTGLevel": [
    {
      "WTG_SCID": "/",
      "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
      "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
      "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
      "WTG_Quantity": 1,
      "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
      "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
      "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
      "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
      "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
      "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
      "component": [
        {
          "Cmpt_Material": "SP_AVI_LAMP_01",
          "Cmpt_Description": "Site Parts Aviation Lamp MSI",
          "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
          "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
          "Cmpt_CapacityType": "NAC_OPT",
          "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 5,
          "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29197892,
          "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR",
          "Cmpt_PriceBaseID": "P/AV_LA:AVWTG_3MW/AV_LA_18/AV_Q_1"
        },
        {
          "Cmpt_Material": "LAMP_01",
          "Cmpt_Description": "Lamp MSI",
          "Cmpt_Quantity": 5,
          "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "fA",
          "Cmpt_CapacityType": "OPT",
          "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 51,
          "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 88899892,
          "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR",
          "Cmpt_PriceBaseID": "AV_LA_18/AV_Q_1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "WTG_SCID": "zyUL6lemDdM",
      "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
      "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
      "WTG_Description": "CS-042692A-#01",
      "WTG_Quantity": 1,
      "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
      "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
      "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
      "WTG_MarkRelease": "3E",
      "WTG_NominalEffect": 4.2,
      "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
      "component": [
        {
          "Cmpt_Material": "DRIVE_TRAIN_01",
          "Cmpt_Description": "Drive Train MSI",
          "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
          "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
          "Cmpt_CapacityType": "DT_V136_4.0ME_3E",
          "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 540,
          "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29219265,
          "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR",
          "Cmpt_PriceBaseID": "P/DT:P_3MW/MK_3E/R_136M/LOC_01"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Code** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "WTGLevel": {
        "*": {
          "component": {
            "*": { // partition the objects by indexes from two different levels
              "@4,guid": "&3_&1.guid",
              "@4,WebHookId": "&3_&1.WebHookId",
              "@4,siteLocation": "&3_&1.siteLocation",
              "@4,ReferenceCountry.RefCountry": "&3_&1.&",
              "@4,ReferenceCountry.Country": "&3_&1.&",
              "@2,WTG_SCID": "&3_&1.WTG_SCID",
              "@2,WTG_ReferenceCountry": "&3_&1.WTG_ReferenceCountry",
              "@2,WTG_Material": "&3_&1.WTG_Material",
              "@2,WTG_Description": "&3_&1.WTG_Description",
              "@2,WTG_Quantity": "&3_&1.WTG_Quantity",
              "@2,WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "&3_&1.WTG_UnitOfMeasure",
              "@2,WTG_WTGType": "&3_&1.WTG_WTGType",
              "@2,WTG_RotorDiameter": "&3_&1.WTG_RotorDiameter",
              "@2,WTG_MarkRelease": "&3_&1.WTG_MarkRelease",
              "@2,WTG_NominalEffect": "&3_&1.WTG_NominalEffect",
              "@2,WTG_HubHeight": "&3_&1.WTG_HubHeight",
              "Cmpt_Material|Cmpt_Quantity|Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure|Cmpt_Description": "&3_&1.&",
              "Cmpt_MaterialGroup|Cmpt_DerivedMaterial|Cmpt_MaterialIndicator|CapacityType": "&3_&1.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // add an array wrapper at the topmost level while getting rid of newly formed object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```

**Excepted Output** : 9 rows

```json
[
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "DE",
    "WTG_SCID": "/",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "SP_AVI_LAMP_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Site Parts Aviation Lamp MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 5,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29197892,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "DE",
    "WTG_SCID": "/",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "LAMP_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 5,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "fA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Lamp MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 51,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 88899892,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "DE",
    "WTG_SCID": "zyUL6lemDdM",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-042692A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3E",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4.2,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "DRIVE_TRAIN_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Drive Train MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 540,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29219265,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "BE",
    "WTG_SCID": "/",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "SP_AVI_LAMP_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Site Parts Aviation Lamp MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 5,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29197892,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "BE",
    "WTG_SCID": "/",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "LAMP_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 5,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "fA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Lamp MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 51,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 88899892,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "BE",
    "WTG_SCID": "zyUL6lemDdM",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-042692A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3E",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4.2,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "DRIVE_TRAIN_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Drive Train MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 540,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29219265,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "NL",
    "WTG_SCID": "/",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "SP_AVI_LAMP_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Site Parts Aviation Lamp MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 5,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29197892,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "NL",
    "WTG_SCID": "/",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-048948A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3F",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4200,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "LAMP_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 5,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "fA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Lamp MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 51,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 88899892,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  },
  {
    "guid": 16161616,
    "WebHookId": 1234567890,
    "siteLocation": "offshore",
    "RefCountry": "DE",
    "Country": "NL",
    "WTG_SCID": "zyUL6lemDdM",
    "WTG_ReferenceCountry": "DE",
    "WTG_Material": "WTG_01",
    "WTG_Description": "CS-042692A-#01",
    "WTG_Quantity": 1,
    "WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "WTG_WTGType": "V136-4.0MW",
    "WTG_RotorDiameter": "136 m",
    "WTG_MarkRelease": "3E",
    "WTG_NominalEffect": 4.2,
    "WTG_HubHeight": 112,
    "Cmpt_Material": "DRIVE_TRAIN_01",
    "Cmpt_Quantity": 1,
    "Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure": "EA",
    "Cmpt_Description": "Drive Train MSI",
    "Cmpt_MaterialGroup": 540,
    "Cmpt_DerivedMaterial": 29219265,
    "Cmpt_MaterialIndicator": "VAR"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concentrically use **`ReferenceCountry`** and **`WTGLevel`** arrays by taking one of them inside while qualifying by **`@2,`** in order to get cross join result **(** 3 **x** 3 **)** for returning the number of objects such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ReferenceCountry": {
        "*": {
          "@2,WTGLevel": {
            "*": {
              "component": {
                "*": { // partition the objects by indexes from two different levels
                  "@6,guid": "&4_&3_&1.guid",
                  "@6,WebHookId": "&4_&3_&1.WebHookId",
                  "@6,siteLocation": "&4_&3_&1.siteLocation",
                  "@4,RefCountry": "&4_&3_&1.RefCountry",
                  "@4,Country": "&4_&3_&1.Country",
                  "@2,WTG_SCID": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_SCID",
                  "@2,WTG_ReferenceCountry": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_ReferenceCountry",
                  "@2,WTG_Material": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_Material",
                  "@2,WTG_Description": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_Description",
                  "@2,WTG_Quantity": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_Quantity",
                  "@2,WTG_UnitOfMeasure": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_UnitOfMeasure",
                  "@2,WTG_WTGType": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_WTGType",
                  "@2,WTG_RotorDiameter": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_RotorDiameter",
                  "@2,WTG_MarkRelease": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_MarkRelease",
                  "@2,WTG_NominalEffect": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_NominalEffect",
                  "@2,WTG_HubHeight": "&4_&3_&1.WTG_HubHeight",
                  "Cmpt_Material|Cmpt_Quantity|Cmpt_UnitOfMeasure|Cmpt_Description": "&4_&3_&1.&",
                  "Cmpt_MaterialGroup|Cmpt_DerivedMaterial|Cmpt_MaterialIndicator|CapacityType": "&4_&3_&1.&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // add an array wrapper at the topmost level while getting rid of newly formed object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```